# Handling and passing errors correctly within async/await

Tags: node.js, async-await, ecmascript-2016

I am writing a small Node.js command line utility. I am packaging it all in one file, and the structure kind of looks like this when simplified:

```
(async() => {
  await someAsyncFunction();
  /* 1 */

  // Iterate through collection and call async functions serially
  array.forEach(async (element) => {
    await anotherAsyncFunction(element);    
  });
})().catch(err => console.log);
```

Now if I throw an error at point 1, the error gets passed to the bottom catch alright. However I want to add error handling to `anotherAsyncFunction` and the for loop surrounding it.

I tried creating the following helper function:

```
async function asyncForEach(array, fn) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i+=1) {
    await fn(array[index], index, array);
  }
}
```

I then rewrote my original iteration code as follows:

```
try {
  await asyncForEach(array, async (element) => {
    await anotherAsyncFunction(element);
  });
} catch (err) {
  throw err;
}
```

While this does work, it seems incredibly verbose. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you even bother adding another try/catch block only to re-throw the error and catch it in the outer catch block??

Comment: @PlatinumIndustries Ah you are correct. I thought I needed that. I removed it and it still works. Thanks.

Comment: @PlatinumIndustries However, the original question still stands, is there a better way to handle errors for awaits inside of a forEach or is this the best way?

Comment: I think it would be better to use one main catch block, unless you still want to continue execution even after an error occurs on one function in the loop

Comment: that is the best way as far as I can tell. That is if you want the script to fail if a function in the for loop raises an error. But if by any chance you want it to continue execution after an error in the for loop, put a try/catch error block and let it fail silently

Comment: Just write `for (const element of array) {
    await anotherAsyncFunction(element);    
  }` and be done with it. No need to introduce helper functions. But if you insist, the call should at least be simplified to `await asyncForEach(array, anotherAsyncFunction);`

Comment: "*Iterate through collection and call async functions serially*" - that's not what `.forEach` does anyway. Don't ever use `forEach`.